# Trying to install scikit-learn shows comman exit out with error status 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I am trying to install the sklearn package and it does not work. I have numpy installed as well as scipy and have tried updating installing tools. I'm using Pycharm on Python 3.10. This is the error message that shows up

```
PS C:\Users\jason\PycharmProjects\pythonProject> pip install scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-1.0.1.tar.gz (6.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\jason\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\jason\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pe
p517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplhn1abe4'
       cwd: C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i9q_z62l\scikit-learn_6c9f7571f4fc41f3a90540d946328d80
  Complete output (46 lines):
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\jason\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\jason\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\jason\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_w
heel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-e2qd4m88\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-e2qd4m88\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-e2qd4m88\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 319, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 315, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-e2qd4m88\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "setup.py", line 201, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage("sklearn")
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-e2qd4m88\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1016, in add_subpackage
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-e2qd4m88\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 982, in get_subpackage
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-e2qd4m88\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 924, in _get_configuration_from_setup
_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn\setup.py", line 85, in configuration
      cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i9q_z62l\scikit-learn_6c9f7571f4fc41f3a90540d946328d80\sklearn\_build_utils\__init__.py", line 47, in cythoniz
e_extensions
      basic_check_build()
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i9q_z62l\scikit-learn_6c9f7571f4fc41f3a90540d946328d80\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 113, i
n basic_check_build
      compile_test_program(code)
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i9q_z62l\scikit-learn_6c9f7571f4fc41f3a90540d946328d80\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 70, in
 compile_test_program
      ccompiler.compile(
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 323, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 220, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-e2qd4m88\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-e2qd4m88\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 270, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
      raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
  distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.c
om/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/62/7c/596ff7b32f655f379d3abdfa82607e5cb3b70f46baad4604706511cfeb85/scikit-learn-1.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=ac2ca9
dbb754d61cfe1c83ba8483498ef951d29b93ec09d6f002847f210a99da (from https://pypi.org/simple/scikit-learn/) (requires-python:>=3.7). Command errored out with exit status
1: 'c:\users\jason\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\scripts\python.exe' 'c:\users\jason\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_p
rocess\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\jason\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplhn1abe4' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.
noted that scilean only supported by python 2.7, 2.8 and 2.9.
so just downgrade python to 2.8 then reinstall scilearn.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with having python 3.10.1 installed in my system (fedora35). This error occured both in my os and virtual environment. Later I installed python3.7 and from venv I could install scikit-learn.Try installing scikit-learn from different python version, which should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).